# c# new Func as an argument

Tags: c#, delegates, arguments, func

I have string.Select set like this:

```
Func<string, int> selector = str => str.Length;
var a = input.Split(splitChars).Select(selector).ToArray()
```

Now is there a way to put the Func delegate right into Select as a **new** argument to spare that one line?

Something like this (but it does not work that way):

```
var a = input.Split(splitChars).Select(new Func<string, int> = str => str.Length).ToArray()
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: you should be able to do just `str => str.Length`

Comment: Jeez, now I feel really dumb, thank you x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a delegate function inside the select like this:

```
var a = input.Split(splitChars).Select(c => c.Length).ToArray();
```

You can input all delegates of form Func<string, T> that way.

Comment: `c` is a weird (misleading) parameter name for a string.

Comment: I'm curious what if the Func took more that one argument.. like: 
Func<string, string, string, int>

How do I handle all three arguments in the new delegate?